# Problem with Swift compiler version in GX16u7

Tags: swift, genexus, swift5, genexus-sd

I'm trying to compile a GX project using Gx16 u7 in a mac running `Xcode 11.3`, I checked the swift installed version and it is `5.1.3` so it should not have problems but I still have.

This is the error that I'm getting when building using Xcode.

> :0: error: module compiled with Swift 5.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler: /Users/genexus/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/16.0.138086_U7/iphonesimulator/GXFoundation.framework/Modules/GXFoundation.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule

Please I really need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19478,iOS%20Requirements) for GeneXus V16 U7 you should install:

XCode   11.2(required)  11.3 (recommended)  with Swift 5.1.2

Could you try with a lower version of XCode (11.2) with Swift 5.1.2?